# How to avoid 'Invalid date' prefix in result when converting from milliseconds (13 digits)

Tags: json, converters, unix-timestamp, epoch

I'm working with converting a 13 digits time stamp fetched from json. Everything seems to work but one - the prefixed **Invalid Date** before the readable time.

Here's the code:

```
var timestamp=new Date(event.feature.getProperty('updated'))
var humanTime=timestamp+Date(1970,1,1);
```

where updated value from json is '`1432205083551`' (13 digits). So the result is :

`Invalid DateTue May 26 2015 19:07:05 GMT+0700 (SE Asia Standard Time)`

It is readable. Everything seems correct but it always begins with `Invalid Date` in every line. Please give me some explanations so I can learn about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Invalid Date part comes from the fact that the first date is constructed using a string. It should be a number (obtainable via `parseInt()`)

```
var timestamp = new Date(parseInt(event.feature.getProperty('updated')))
```

On a sidenote i don't understand what you use the `humanTime` variable for... `event.feature.getProperty('updated')` already seems to be the number of milliseconds since 1970. Printing a human readable timestamp can be done just by calling `toString()`:

```
alert(timestamp.toString())
```